# GIT find files not under source control

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I discovered a file in my project that are not under source control.
I then add it to source control, and all is well.
Is there a GIT command line I could execute to check if there are any other files not under source control?

I've tried a number of options on 'GIT LS-FILES', but haven't found anything that reveals the files.

[image: Not Under Source Control]

Comment: `git status` - add `-s --ignored` to see things in `.gitignore` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `git ls-files` : you can use

```
git ls-files --exclude-standard -o
```

---

`-o` is short for [`--others`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#Documentation/git-ls-files.txt--o) :

> `-o`
> `--others`
>
> Show other (i.e. untracked) files in the output

By default, `git ls-files` does not honor the `.gitignore` files, you have to add `--exclude-standard` if you want to hide files that should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks.    I thought I had tried that, and it returned nothing.    I've since added my file to source control.
Next time it happens, I will remember to try this.

Thanks!